# Qt add statically parameters to connect directive

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

My code looks like this:

```
connect(c_name, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int) ), employeesList, SLOT(changeVisibility(int)));
```

where `c_name` is a `QCheckBox`, and i would like to connect its `stateChange` to the visibility of an attribute in `employeesList`, which method looks like this:

```
void changeVisibility(int prop, int visibility){
        if(prop & EmployeeListElement::Name)
            updateVisibility(&EmployeeListElement::name, visibility);
        if(prop & EmployeeListElement::Surname)
            updateVisibility(&EmployeeListElement::surname, visibility);
        if(prop & EmployeeListElement::DateOfBirth)
            updateVisibility(&EmployeeListElement::date_of_birth, visibility);
        if(prop & EmployeeListElement::DateOfEmployment)
            updateVisibility(&EmployeeListElement::date_of_empl, visibility);

    }
private:
    void updateVisibility(QLabel* EmployeeListElement::* elem, int visibility){
        visibility ? (this->*elem)->show() : (this->*elem)->hide();
    }
...
```

as you can see, i need to pass a second parameter, that is the property i'm referring to, so I would like to do something like this:

```
connect(c_name, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int) ), employeesList, SLOT(changeVisibility(int, Class::first_enum_property)));
```

that does not work, an my question is, are there ways to do it? maybe without using `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` directive and using some (maybe) lambdas?

Comment: Lambdas should be the solution, see https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using lambdas should indeed resolve your problem:

```
connect(c_name, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, employeesList, [employeesList](int visibility){employeesList->changeVisibility(Class::first_enum_property, visibility);});
```

Note that the third argument (i.e. the [context object](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5)) is optional, but useful to automatically destruct the connection when `employeesList` is destroyed.

**References**

- https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax#New:_connecting_to_simple_function

Comment: Should not be `employeesList->changeVisibility(Class::first_enum_property, state);`?

Comment: @scopchanov, probably yes (I edited my answer). Note that the OP himself is inconsistent concerning the argument order. (Compare the `changeVisibility` declaration and the `SLOT` of his (non-working) `connect` call.)

Comment: Yep. So it is. I was unsure where to comment and the answer, where the errors are pointed out, seemed a better place to me than the question.